"NETSDK1130: Can't reference a Windows Metadata component directly" does not actually work
I wanted to add bluetooth functionality to my wpf net 8.0 app. However when adding using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;, I get an error saying the Windows namespace cannot be found.
Looking at the setup of older apps with bluetooth, I see that they reference this namespace using a Windows.winmd. After adding this to my project I get the error that a Windows Metadata component cannot be referenced when targeting .net 5+. I go to this link mentionned in the error message : https://aka.ms/netsdk1130 which tells me to add TargetFramework to my project file.
But TargetFramework already exists : <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>, so I'm just back to square one. The app compiles fine without bluetooth references. How am I meant to find out what's wrong here ?

I have no experience doing this but I found this Open Source library: 32feet.NET and here is a tutorial for it: Transferring Data via Bluetooth in .NET.

Okay, you need to specify the exact folder name for the .net sdk in TargetFramework. If you use the one generated by Visual Studio (like just "net8.0") it won't work. Thank you Microsoft.
